# PHP remove regex from string, but keep match & rest

Tags: php, regex

is there a way in php to have a combined preg_match_all and preg_replace?

Having a string `$string` like:

> Lorem Ipsum `code block` lorem `code`

I want to remove the code blocks from the string and keep $string (without the code blocks) but also keep an array of matches, like I would get with preg_mach_all.

```
[
  0 => `code block`,
  1 => `code`
]
```

Is this possible in one command in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$s = 'Lorem Ipsum `code block` lorem `code`';

$matches = array(); // array to keep removed matches
$repl = preg_replace_callback('/(`[^`]*`)\h*/', function($m) use(&$matches) {
            $matches[]=$m[1]; return ''; }, $s);

echo $repl . "\n";
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Lorem Ipsum lorem
Array
(
    [0] => `code block`
    [1] => `code`
)
```